# Neo4j - Importing millions of data with relationship creation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been trying to import 3 different CSV files with the third file containing 3M data. creation of relationship between file 1 and file 2 was successful as there was not much of data. But creation of relationship between file 2 and file 3 was not successful. The data structure is as follows.

File 1: (This has 2 headers) Data sample for eg

```
HEADER1,HEADER2
'A','B'
```

File2:(This has two headers) values in HEADER2 common between file1 and file2

```
HEADER2,HEADER3                                                                  
'B','C'
```

File3: (This has 4 headers) values in Header3 common between file2 and file3
This file has 3M values

```
HEADER3,HEADER4,HEADER5,HEADER6
'C','D','E','F'
```

I want to create relationships between nodes as follows:  If a `:file1` node has a `HEADER2` property that is equal to a `:file2` node's `HEADER2` property, then a relationship should be created between those nodes. And a relationship should be created similarly between `:file2`/`:file3` nodes using their `HEADER3` properties.

I'm using the following code to load data but the JVM is going out of memory since the relationship creation is in very high number :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 50000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///D:/file3.csv" as csvline
MATCH (file2:file2 {HEADER3: csvline.HEADER3}) 
create (file3:file3 {HEADER3: csvline.HEADER3, HEADER4: toString(csvline.HEADER4), HEADER5: toString(csvline.HEADER5), HEADER6: csvline.HEADER6})
CREATE (file2)-[:HAS_SERVICE]->(file3)
```

The JVM is going Out of memory with "gc overhead limit exceeded" error on the browser.
Any pointers on how to create relationship between file1 , file 2 and file 3 where there are millions of rows would be helpful !!

Comment: So, your actual data files have commas (",") between each value on a row, yes?

Comment: With `MATCH (scc:file1 {HEADER2 : file2.HEADER2})--(css:file2 {HEADER3 : file3.HEADER3})`, aren't you trying to match a relationship that doesn't exist yet? ... or is that relationship created somewhere else?

Comment: @rickhg12hs. The file has comma separated between each value in a row. I tried to match relationship that doesn’t exist, even then it’s going OOM.

Comment: Could you please guide me on adding more filter criteria ?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how you want the relationships to work?  I.e., what do they mean?  Which features of the nodes, or input files/rows, are you using to decide if a relationship should exist between nodes?

Comment: File 1 and file 2 contains very less data  so relationship between them is straightforward. Pain point is between 2 and 3. In file 2, header3 parameter are repeated. Relationship should be between file2 and file3 where header3 parameter matches. Its many to many relationship.

Comment: So, just to be clear ... if a `:file1` node has a `HEADER2` property that is equal to a `:file2` node's `HEADER2` property, then you create a relationship between the nodes? ... And you'd like to do the same with `:file2`/`:file3` nodes using the `HEADER3` property?

Comment: Exactly. You got it right!!!

Comment: I think a strategy similar to the [Import data](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/3.5/cypher-intro/load-csv/) chapter of Neo4j's intro doc will work for your data.  I.e., create the relationships as you import each new CSV file.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I tried with the following, "USING PERIODIC COMMIT 2000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///D:/file3.csv" as csvline
MATCH (file2:file2 {HEADER3: csvline.HEADER3}) 
create (file3:file3 {HEADER3: csvline.HEADER3, HEADER4: toString(csvline.HEADER4), HEADER5: toString(csvline.HEADER5), HEADER6: csvline.HEADER6})
CREATE (file2)-[:HAS_SERVICE]->(file3)". Still unable to import the data.

Comment: Is there an error message?... OOM? Did you try without any `WITH *` statements? Perhaps it would be best if you showed your new complete code by editing your original post and putting it at the end with a note about what happened when you tried to use it.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have edited the post and added the code which is used. I havent used any WITH * statements in the code.

Comment: Is there any difference if you use a smaller `PERIODIC COMMIT`?  I think the default is 1000.  Maybe try the default or even smaller?

Comment: I have tried with 500 as well and failed. Currently I'm planning to split the file into multiple parts and then import.